# DNS record look up with Python / Django [dnspython]

Tags: python, django, dns, dnspython

I am trying to get DNS records of particular domain. So, I found `dnspython` package where it could be easily done. It works fine when I run it from my computer. However, when I call it from Django views it shows the **previous records (old records)** which means it's not updating.

Is it some kind of caching in OS level? Note that, I am also using **Docker**. Restarting docker and clearing cache in Django didn't help, still shows old records.

Here's the sample code for checking records:

```
import dns.resolver
result = dns.resolver.resolve("domain.com", "TXT")[0].to_text()
```

The code snippet above works and shows any update in TXT record, when I run it from my computer. However, in Django it's stuck in old records and not updating.

In Django views:

```
def verify_dns_view(request, domain_id):
    domain = get_object_or_404(models.Domain, id=domain_id)
    mx_record = dns.resolver.resolve(domain.name, "MX")[0].to_text()
    txt_record_spf = dns.resolver.resolve(domain.name, "TXT")[0].to_text()
    ...
```

Comment: could you plase paste the actual view code that uses this function?

Comment: well my guess was that you were calling it outside the view so it sayed static but it seems okay. Probaby problem lays with `resolve` function itself. Try jumping to their docs. My other guess it that your PC actually connects to different dns server (which has updated record already) than your app server (which has still old record)

Comment: @quqa123 Yes! Your second guess is right. I tested from different servers and they are showing updated values. You can post this as an answer and I will accept it. Now, at least I know where the problem appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There always might be a different DNS server that your app and PC are connecting to. In your case app server is "further away" from the server where the actual domain is registered so it did not update the record yet.